# How to delete every nth row of an if one contains a zero?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array containing data for three different indicators (X-Z) in five different categories (A-E).
Now I want to check every column from the dataset whether there is a 0 in it. In case there is a 0 in a row, I want to delete all indicators of this type.

In my minimum example it should find the zero in one of the Y rows and consequently delete all Y rows.

```
AA =(['0','A','B','C','D','E'],
     ['X','2','3','3','3','4'],
     ['Y','3','4','9','7','3'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'],
     ['X','2','3','3','3','4'],
     ['Y','3','4','8','7','0'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'],
     ['X','2','5','3','3','4'],
     ['Y','3','4','0','7','3'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'])
```

My code is the following:

```
    import numpy as np
    sequence = 3 #number of columns per sequence X,Y,Z 

    AA = np.array(AA)  
    for i in range(1,AA.shape[0]):
        for j in range(1,AA.shape[1]):
            if j == 0.0:
                for k in range(np.min((j-1)/sequence,1),AA.shape[0],sequence):                  
                    np.delete(AA, k, 0)
```

and should give me:

```
AA =(['0','A','B','C','D','E'],
     ['X','2','3','3','3','4'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'],
     ['X','2','3','3','3','4'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'],
     ['X','2','5','3','3','4'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'])
```

But somehow my code does not delete anything. So I guess I have a problem with the delete function, but I can't figure out what exactly the problem is.

EDIT:
In my real data the indicators (X-Z) don't have all exactly the same name but rather 'asdf - X' or 'qwer - Y - asdf'. So always the label part after the first '-' separator is identical.

So I cannot use a set() function on them but rather have to select the rows to delete by the distances from the row where the 0 was detected.

Comment: The problem is before the delete function. I think j is never equal to 0 since it runs from 1 to AA.shape[1]. You want AA[i,j] to be 0

Comment: @Glostas, thanks a lot for your input! Even though I'm very new to coding I should have noticed this one. But even with this adaptation `if AA[i,j] == 0.0:` my delete function does not work.

Comment: I didn't really check it. In AA you have strings and 0.0 is a float. This can never be equal. Try if if AA[i,j] is '0'. As a general tip: use print ('enter if') or something to check if the code gets into your if statements

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try the 'enter if' trick in my next problems!

Comment: Um, you didn't answer my question about the labels. How "not exactly the same" are they?

Comment: How do YOU know what the "X" part of a label is?

Comment: I just read your question again and adjusted the edit accordingly. And I know that the 'X' part is everything that follows the first '-' separator as I can also have a second '-' being part of the 'X'.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you store the column/row names _inside_ the data array itself? This makes handling the data a pain, since you will be dealing with strings instead of floats.

Comment: I have the names inside the array since I thought it would be easier this way when the column names are deleted together with the columns (which is exactly what I want) and I read also my data from a source that includes them already. However in later data processing I separate the titles from the numbers so I could also adjust the name list there.

Comment: Keeping the ID with every row is good practice, since it allows the rows to be self-describing. The column names can easily be stripped by writing `AA[1:]`.

Comment: @Dave, if it's really "everything that follows the first `-` separator", getting the label is as simple as `row[0].split("-", 1)[1]`. (and maybe an extra `.strip()` on that, if the whitespace is really there.) But what about the "asdf" part in your `'qwer - Y - asdf'` example? I'm anticipating more corrections...

Comment: @alexis, thank you so so much!! It worked out as you suggested. As I stated above, I'm still very new to coding and am very grateful for support like yours! ps: the - asdf was also part of the second element of the label, but it worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it in two passes. It is a lot cleaner, and it might even be faster under some circumstances. Here's an implementation without numpy; feel free to convert it to use `array()`.

```
AA =(['0','A','B','C','D','E'],
     ['X','2','3','3','3','4'],
     ['Y','3','4','9','7','3'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'],
     ['X','2','3','3','3','4'],
     ['Y','3','4','8','7','0'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4'],
     ['X','2','5','3','3','4'],
     ['Y','3','4','0','7','3'],
     ['Z','3','4','6','3','4']) 

todrop = set(row[0] for row in AA[1:] if '0' in row)
filtered = list(row for row in AA[1:] if row[0] not in todrop)
```

Since `row[0]` does not contain the exact indicator label, write a simple function that will extract the label and use that instead of the entire `row[0]`. Details depend on what your data *actually* looks like.

**Option 2:** In case you *really* want to do it by counting the rows (which I don't recommend): Save the row numbers modulo 3, instead of the row ID. It's about the same amount of work:

```
relabeled = list((n % 3, row) for n, row in enumerate(AA[1:]))
todrop = set(n for n, row in relabeled if '0' in row)  # Will save {1} for Y
filtered = list(row for n, row in relabeled if n not in todrop)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a great way of solving it for the minimum example. Unfortunately, I put this example a bit too simplistic as the names X,Y,Z are not exactly the same but rater 'X - asdf', 'X-asd', 'Xasdf' so I know only the distances between the rows I want to delete exactly. Nevertheless I will try whether I can somehow store the index and then add up a multiple of the distances as I tried it with "sequence" in my code.

Comment: If the names `X`, `Y`, `Z` can be systematically extracted from the actual labels, then it's a pretty small modification to the above. Add a paragraph to the question to explain the naming-- is the first letter enough, for example? I know your title was about deleting every n-th row, but I went by the question text since it's more robust if both approaches are possible.

Comment: I will try it with using the 'extractable' part of the labels or otherwise the row counting. As soon as I succeeded, I can let you know by checking your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to delete something while looping through it, and it will not work, since it will lose the references.
Instead of deleting current matrix, try to build another one with the values you want to, and then assign the matrix to the one you just created